# Are there any privacy issues associated with scanning the QR codes in Fez?

Tags: fez

I want to play and enjoy the game I paid for, but don't want any spam, or to be "tracked".

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Fez*'s QR codes are all text-type.

All text is embedded within the symbol, so it can be accessed offline.

[image: See? It's just text. And even offline scanners can read it]

QR code readers reading URL-type codes will bring you to websites when viewed from an Internet-connected smartphone (which can then track you), but *Fez* doesn't use those QR code types.

Comment: To the extent "type-type" QR codes exist, QR codes encoding URLs _are_ "text-type" QR codes. The text they contain happens to be URLs. No QR code can push anything; only poorly implemented QR code _scanners_ can do that.

Comment: Just because it's not an URL doesn't mean Fez can't communicate that code to a server and track you that way.

Comment: @kotekzot: This was a while ago, but I believe I tested them offline

Comment: Doesn't have to be transmitted immediately. Store the time and code, send when a connection is available.

Comment: @kotekzot: What you're saying doesn't make any sense. You scan the code on e.g. your phone (or a generic QR decoding website, or by hand with pencil and paper), which is not running Fez. Fez has no idea you scanned the code. If Fez wanted to report to a server, it could just _do that_ without showing you a QR code.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig ah, I see. I assumed there was a special app to scan them in.

Answer (score 13):

QR codes are just like a barcode. They can't, by themselves, communicate over the Internet or track you in any way.

Most of the QR codes in *Fez* don't contain URLs, so if you are scanning them on a device that automatically opens a scanned QR code as a link, it won't work anyway.